# What is the maximum number of xxx of db-xxx in kahaDB (ActiveMQ)?

Tags: activemq-classic, kahadb

I'm looking for the maximum number of `xxx` of `db-xxx.log` in kahaDB (ActiveMQ).

I set the db file configuration in `activemq.xml` for a production site as below.

```xml
<persistenceAdapter>
  <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb" journalMaxFileLength="32mb" cleanupInterval="5000"/>
</persistenceAdapter>
```

The remained kahadb files currently are `db-5.log` and `db-6.log`, but I'm not sure the maximum index number (`xxx` of `db-xxx.log`) and the behavior when reached the maximum number like `db-9999999.log`.

Comment: What size is your disk? A 10TB disk can hold around 32,000 32MB files. You're way more likely to run out of disk space before you hit the maximum index value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The db file number is a Java int value. Therefore, the theoretical max number of db-*.log files is Integer.MAX_VALUE or 2,147,483,647.